# Bluebird Promise serial iteration, and resolve to modified array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I have this promise that creates a new `Item` document if it's not found in the db, and then stores it in a previously created `Collection` document..

The Collection document is the first string in an array, and any subsequent index in the array translates to one or more Item docs.

Promise.each ["Resolves to the original array unmodified"](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#eachfunction-iterator---promise) and so the last `return` within the `Promise.each` is rendering the objects, but the subsequent `.then` produces the original array..

Here's the promise (abbreviated for readability):

```
globalVar = true;
collectionId = "";
var itemSeries = Promise.each(items, function(element) {
    if (globalVar == true) {
        return Models.Collection.findOneAsync({
            "name": element
        })
        .then(function(collection) {
            // promise chain similar to the following else..
            // set the collectionId var to an _id
        });
    } else {
        return Models.Items.findOneAsync({
            "name": element
        })
        .then(function(item) {
            if (item == null) {
                return Models.Labels.findOneAsync({
                    "title": element
                })
                .then(function(label) {
                    var newItem = new Models.Items({
                        name: element,
                        label: label._id
                    });
                    return newItem.saveAsync();
                }).then(function() {
                    return Models.Items.findOneAsync({
                        "name": element
                    });
                }).then(function(item) {
                    item.collection = collectionId;
                    return item.saveAsync();
                }).then(function() {
                    return Models.Items.findOneAsync({
                        "name": element
                    });
                }).then(function(item) {
                    allItems.push(item);
                    console.log("allItems: [ ");
                    console.log(allItems);
                    return allItems;
                });
            }
        });
    }
}).then(function(allItems) {
    console.log("allItems: [ ");
    console.log(allItems);
    return allItems;
});
```

And here's the last of the `console.log` within the Promise.each:

```
allItems: [ 
[ { _id: 54eec5f2b9fb280000286d52,
    name: 'one',
    label: 54eec5f2b9fb280000286d51,
    collection: 54eec5f2b9fb280000286d50,
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 54eec5f2b9fb280000286d54,
    name: 'two',
    label: 54eec5f2b9fb280000286d53,
    collection: 54eec5f2b9fb280000286d50,
    __v: 0 } ]
```

And then after the subsequent `.then(function(allItems) {` here's the last `console.log`:

```
allItems: [ 
[ 'collectionName', 'one', 'two' ]
```

Also, the variable `itemSeries` that `= Promise.each` later renders `undefined` in a Promise.join?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `.each` function will not change the value that is *passed* through the chain:

I simplified your code, as input I assume:

```
var items = ['one','two'];
```

For your code:

```
Promise.each(items, function(element) {
    return element+'.';
    //return Promise.resolve(element+'.');
})
.then(function(allItems) {
    console.dir(allItems);
});
```

The result will still be `['one','two']` because this are resolved values of the array `items`. The returned value within the each does not influence the content of the value passed to the chained `then`.

The `.map` function on the other hand will have this effect:

```
Promise.map(items, function(element) {
    return element+'.';
    //return Promise.resolve(element+'.');
})
.then(function(allItems) {
    console.dir(allItems);
});
```

Here the `return` value value will be used to create a new array which will then be passed to the `then`. Here the result would be `['one.','two.']`.

The two `allItems` appearing in your code are different objects.

**EDIT**
For serially iteration with mapping I would write a helper function like this:

```
 function mapSeries(things, fn) {
     var results = [];
     return Promise.each(things, function(value, index, length) {
         var ret = fn(value, index, length);
         results.push(ret);
         return ret;
     }).thenReturn(results).all();
 }
```

Source: [Implement Promise.series](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/134#issuecomment-63012938)

Comment: Alright, how can the `allItems` value be returned? .each is necessary because sequence is required..

Comment: fwiw  .each will work like .mapSeries in 3.0 since returning the existing array hasnt been useful

Comment: @Esailija oh thats good to know. I'm pretty sure relay on that behavior somewhere -.-

Comment: Instead of writing a mapSeries function, bluebirds's Promise.reduce can also do the trick. https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/70

Answer (score 1):

Bluebird now natively implements a `mapSeries`, see http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.mapseries.html

It also looks like `Promise.each` still returns the original array unfortunately in v3.x.x.