# Convert nested 'for' loops into a Promise, for a Promise? Nested Promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I have an array where the values are sequences separated by '/', and a '[mapSeries](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/134#issuecomment-63012938)' Promise (helper function for serially iteration with mapping) that loops through each value within each of the sequences.

Right now, the statement starts with a nested 'for' loop that splits a sequence into strings, and then pushes these values to an empty array to hand off to the 'mapSeries' promise..

*After testing, it turns out that this only works if the original array has one sequence because multiple sequences run in parallel.*

**How can this be written as a promise that runs serially for each sequence, and then serially for each element in the given sequence?**

Here's the attempt at the for loop (works for a single sequence):

```
var sequences = ['one/two/three', 'alpha/beta'];
var elements = [];
for (i=0; i<sequences.length; i++) {
  var series = sequences[i].split("/");
  for (j=0; j<series.length; j++) {
    elements.push(series[j]);
  }
    var items = mapSeries(elements, function(element) {
        // do stuff with 'one', then 'two', then 'three'
        // when done..next series
        // do stuff with 'alpha', then 'beta'
    })
    elements = []; // reset elements array for next series
} // for sequences.length
```

And here's an attempt at a Promise (error at element.charAt..):

```
var sequences = ['one/two/three', 'alpha/beta'];
var elements = [];
var items = mapSeries(sequences, function(sequence) {
    sequence = sequence.split("/");
    return mapSeries(sequence, function(series) {
        elements.push(series);
        return elements;
    }).then(function(elements) {
        return mapSeries(elements, function(element){
            var element = element.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + element.slice(1); // first letter lowercase
            // do stuff with 'one', then 'two', then 'three'
            // when done..next series
            // do stuff with 'alpha', then 'beta'
        });
    });
    elements = []; // reset elements array for next series
});
```

mapSeries helper function:

```
function mapSeries(things, fn) {
  var results = [];
  return Promise.each(things, function(value, index, length) {
    var ret = fn(value, index, length);
    results.push(ret);
    return ret;
  }).thenReturn(results).all();
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need that `elements` array, just use return values. Can you show us your `mapSeries` helper function?

Comment: Do you actually use an asynchronous function somewhere? If yes, please show its call, if no you should not need `mapSeries`.

Comment: @Bergi here's the async call: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28736452/bluebird-promise-serial-iteration-and-resolve-to-modified-array, and the answer shows the mapSeries helper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of the code seems pretty useless as `elements` is the same as `sequence`, and pushing is not asynchronous so you could use a `for` loop as well:

> ```
> sequence = sequence.split("/");
> return mapSeries(sequence, function(series) {
>     elements.push(series);
>     return elements;
> })
> ```

Also you've probably got a bug in there as

> ```
> elements = []; // reset elements array for next series
> ```

is never executed - it is after a `return` statement; and won't wait for asynchronous results anyway.

Your code should simply omit those `elements` array, and just be

```
var sequences = ['one/two/three', 'alpha/beta'];
var items = mapSeries(sequences, function(sequence) {
    return mapSeries(sequence.split("/"), function(elements) {
        return mapSeries(elements, function(element) {
            // do async stuff with the element, and return a promise
        });
    });
});
```

Btw, instead of that custom `mapSeries` implementation I recommend to use Bluebird's "native" [`map` method](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#mapfunction-mapper--object-options---promise) with the [`concurrency` option](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#option-concurrency) set to `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Some fast, ugly, not tested example, but I hope you get the idea:

```
var sequences = ['one/two/three', 'alpha/beta'];
var elements = [];
var promise = null;

for (var i = 0; i < sequences.length; i++) {
    (function(series){
        function doStuff() {
            for (var j = 0; j < series.length; j++) {
                elements.push(series[j]);
            }

            return mapSeries(elements, function(element) {
                // async stuff
            })
        }

        if (promise) {
            promise = promise.then(doStuff)
        } else {
            promise = doStuff()
        }
    })( sequences[i].split("/") )
}

promise.then(function(){
    // ...    
})
```