# Global scope of last insertId using node.js + mysql

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am calling function in order to insert some values into a database table using `mysql` module of `node.js`. The function is called inside a `for` loop and I can get the last `insertId` of each `INSERT` query inside the function.

**MY PURPOSE**

I want to store these `id's` to an array in to order to use them later in my code but I **cannot** do that.

**- FUNCTION CALL**

```
 for(var i=0;i<some_number;i++){
   if (<something is true>){

  var lastid = [];
  //Function calling
  function_a(x, y, z, w,  function(error, result) {
   if(!error){
       lastid.push(result.insertId);
       }
   //To Do
   else{}
  });
 }
}
```

**- FUNCTION**

```
function function_a(a, b, c, d, callback){
//Connection to the DB
const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'host',
  user: 'user',
  password: 'password',
  database: 'database'
});

//DB query
var query = "INSERT INTO my_table (column1, column1, column1, column1) VALUES ('"+a+"', '"+b+"', '"+c+"', '"+d+"')";
con.query(query, (err, rows) => {
 var e = rows.insertId;
 return callback(err, e);
});
con.end(); 
}
```

The problem is that I cannot use the id's outside the function.

Any idea how can I do that?Is this about variable scope?

Answer (score 0):

Several problems here, and yes, they are partly about variable scope.

Put `var lastid = [];` before the for loop, so you can use it after the loop. However, as you have callback mechanism inside the loop, you must wait for the whole loop to finish (all callbacks called from 0 to `some_number-1`, in order to have the right values in `lastid` array. It's a messy thing with callbacks, but you can do it with them or with promises. You can Google for callback handling in for loops.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I finally believe this is about variable scope when using callback functions.Every try I made `array` with id's is always empty.Do you have any example that can help me?

Comment: It is empty, because you are calling it after the for loop, however, there is no guarantee that the for loop finished it's iterations. That is happening because of the async operations in it (database queries, for example). In order to do it right, you can look at [this loop callback pattern](http://www.richardrodger.com/2011/04/21/node-js-how-to-write-a-for-loop-with-callbacks/#.WcixIFuCyUk), or [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28736452/bluebird-promise-serial-iteration-and-resolve-to-modified-array) of promise.each() function use.

Answer (score 0):

The function `function_a` is a `asynchronous` function. In your case you can use `async` module to do this task:

```
var taskIds = Array.apply(null, {length: some_number}).map(Number.call, Number);
var lastid = [];
async.eachLimit(taskIds, 32, function (taskId, done) {
  if (<something is true>) {
    function_a(x, y, z, w,  function(error, result) {
      if(!error){
        lastid.push(result.insertId);
      }
      //To Do
      else{}
      done()
    });
  } else {
    done()
  }
}, function () { 
  // Do some thing with lastid
  console.log(lastid);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it doesn't work..Should I require some module for `async.eachLimit`?

Comment: @GeoDim Yes, `async` is a helper module like `mysql`. https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html